# How do I renable the Rider Deamon?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Project Rider: I have no idea how I got into tthe state but code analysis is disabled. I get a popup that says

> Code Analysis Has Been Suspended
>   (Rider deamon is suspended)

How do I turn this back on?

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details, like which OS, Rider EAP version and what you've already tried so far (restarting Rider, reboot system etc.). But, you might want to try running Analyze > Inspect Code manually to start with.

Comment: I should close this. Seems like it was just a random bug in the EAP. I was on version 17 when it happened, and I have not been able to reproduce it since. After closing and restarting rider (full exit) it came back. My original assumption was that there was a button to enable, or restart the service when running rider in internal mode.